# how to call netty encode method manually in java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, netty, quartz

i want know how to call manually netty MessageToByteEncoder class encode() method.
This is because certain packets need to be sent periodically to devices connected to the channel.

I am trying to send packets to the device at regular intervals by periodically calling the encode method through the quartz library.
How is it possible?
As a necessary parameter value of the Encode method, two more are needed besides the ChannelHandlerContext class.
How can I fill this part?

The part I want to implement is that a specific value is periodically transmitted to the connected device through the channel connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this... You should just use `ChannelHandlerContext.write(...)` or `Channel.write(...)` for this